# Screen turns off on dual boot of Windows7 and Ubuntu11.10

Tags: dual-boot, 11.10, screen, acer, aspire

I'm dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 using wubi, and when I turn on my computer it takes me to the boot manager screen and I pick Ubuntu. After that it takes me to the purple screen and asks me which version I want to boot (normal or safe mode) -- I pick normal. After I pick normal, I get another purple screen and then my screen turns off and I can't see anything. Is there a code or command that I can execute to keep my screen on?

Comment: What video card is it ?

Comment: im actually not sure. Its brand new, like new new. Acer Aspire

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this bug several times with different Acer models (mostly Travelmate).

The information here has some good information how to fix this (*if* it is really this bug):
https://launchpad.net/~kamalmostafa/+archive/linux-kamal-mjgbacklight

It deals with editing `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/rc.local` but you should follow these steps *after* you have installed Ubuntu.

For the installation I found the following workarounds (only one or a combination of both is perhaps needed):

- When the BIOS messages are displayed, just press the key combination
  `FN + Brightness_Key` to turn your screen a little bit darker or
  brighter. After that the install GUI should show up as expected.
- Add `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` to the the kernel command
  line when booting the installer.